# How do I use angularjs OrderBy and ng-repeat to iterate a list incrementally(10 second intervals)?

Tags: angularjs

How do I iterate over this list of people using age, starting at the youngest, I would like to stop on each age for 10 seconds before going to the next age. It should work like this all the ones are displayed, then ten seconds later all the twos are added to the display and so on. Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
<script>
angular.module('orderByExample', [])
.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.friends =
      [{name:'John', phone:'555-1212', age:1},
       {name:'Mary', phone:'555-9876', age:1},
       {name:'Mike', phone:'555-4321', age:2},
       {name:'Adam', phone:'555-5678', age:3},
       {name:'Julie', phone:'555-8765', age:4}];
}]);
</script>

<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <table class="friend">
<tr>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Phone Number</th>
  <th>Age</th>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | orderBy:'-age'">
  <td>{{friend.name}}</td>
  <td>{{friend.phone}}</td>
  <td>{{friend.age}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`filter`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) to filter your list of people. Then you just need to increment your age filter every 10 seconds.

Here's an example using `$interval` (set to 3 seconds instead of 10 for demo purposes).

```js
angular.module('orderByExample', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', '$interval',
    function($scope, $interval) {
      $scope.friends =
        [{name:'John', phone:'555-1212', age:1},
         {name:'Mary', phone:'555-9876', age:1},
         {name:'Mike', phone:'555-4321', age:2},
         {name:'Adam', phone:'555-5678', age:3},
         {name:'Julie', phone:'555-8765', age:4}];

      // define what to filter by
      $scope.filter = {
        age: 1
      };

      $interval(function() {
        // every N seconds, increment the age to filter by 1
        $scope.filter.age++;
      }, 3000);
    }
  ]);
```

```html
<div ng-app="orderByExample">

  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <table class="friend">
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Phone Number</th>
        <th>Age</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter: filter">
        <td>{{friend.name}}</td>
        <td>{{friend.phone}}</td>
        <td>{{friend.age}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.js"></script>
```

Comment: You should manually stop the `$interval`, otherwise it will run even after the app is navigated away from

Comment: Thanks. this really helped.

Comment: @NewDev That's true (assuming you're referring to an in-Angular navigation). It could also help to loop through valid ages rather than always incrementing by 1. For example, if there was a gap between age 4 and 94, you'd have to wait 900 seconds, not 10. But I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader ;)